# How can get the Venue data and their photos data by Foursquare

Tags: uitableview, foursquare

Now I am doing a Swift app by Foursquare. I have to fetch the Venue data and the photo of it at the same time. But the use Foursquare api to fetch the Venue photo data needs the Venue ID, which means cannot do the two fetch together? Can I do that together?

Comment: Which endpoint are you using to fetch the venue? You need a Venue Id to get venue details as well so you should be able to call details and photos with the same venue Id

Answer (score 0):

you can use Explore API ... with "venuePhotos=1 filter 
like this:

```
http://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=54.6872,25.2797&venuePhotos=1
```